# How to read HTTP POST request with the class return type in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how can I read the HTTP post response with the class return type?

my class is

```
 class ContactModal {

  String code;
  String status;
  String name;

  ContactModal({this.code, this.status, this.name});

  factory ContactModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ContactModal(
        code: json['code'],
        status: json['status'],
        name: json['name']

    );
  }
}
```

and my HTTP request is

```
class ApiClient {
      Future<ContactModal> getDetails(String token) async {

        print("inside get file "+token);
        var response = await http
            .get(Uri.parse(this.apiBaseUrl + "/file-list/"), headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Authorization":  token
        });

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print("Json response"+response.body);
          return ContactModal.fromJson(json.jsonDecode(response.body));
        } else {
          print("Json exception response");
          throw Exception('Failed to fetch access token');
        }
}
      }
```

my builder is

```
     body: new Container(
          child: new FutureBuilder(
            future: apiClient.getFileDetails(this.accessToken),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print(" prefs.getString('accessTokenValue') "+snapshot.data);
             if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print("Snap shot data : "+snapshot.data);
                new ContactsList(_buildContactList(snapshot));

              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
// By default, show a loading spinner
              return new CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
```

my api will return the response `List[ContactModal]()`
How can i read the all data and am getting everytime **snapshot result null.**

Comment: What is the value of json after successful

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian my json response is `[{"code":"1234","status":"N","name":"A"},{"code":"234","status":"N","name":"B"},{"code":"34","status":"N","name":"B"},{"code":"7665","status":"N","name":"ABC"},{"code":"35456","status":"N","name":"SDA"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Your response contains  `array of contact json`. So you might have to build the contact list and return like below.

```
 var jsonArray = json.jsonDecode(response.body);
var contactList = jsonArray.map((json) => ContactModal.fromJson(json)).toList();
```

Return type of getDetails will be `Future<List<ContactModal>>`.

Comment: Dinesh am getting this issue  `The following ArgumentError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<ContactModal>>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 7226): _FutureBuilderState<List<ContactModal>>#50d94):
I/flutter ( 7226): Invalid argument(s)`

Comment: After applying this code `FutureBuilder<List<ContactModal>>(
            future: apiClient.getFileDetails(this.accessToken),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ContactModal>> snapshot) {` am getting `snapshot` result null

Comment: bro in API response am getting the response but before returning response my `FutureBuilder ` executing and returned the snapshot null after that am getting API response

Comment: As you are checking snapshot.hasData, snapshot.data should not be null inside if block.. can u print the contactList before returning